# Kubernetes object with owner reference deleted

Tags: kubernetes

I've implemented a controller for Custom Resource (CR) A by `controller-runtime` lib. CR A is dependent on resource B as

```yaml
apiVersion: CRD.API.Version
kind: A
metadata:
  name: a
spec:
  bName: b
  otherSpecs: ...
```

And I add `ownerReference` on B instances in my controller when A is reconciled, which enables my controller `Watches` B and would trigger a reconciliation for A if its dependent B is updated. Besides, when A is deleted, related `ownerReference` on B would be removed:

```golang
func (r *MyReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&A{}).
        Watches(&source.Kind{Type: &B{}}, &handler.EnqueueRequestForOwner{OwnerType: &A{}, IsController: false}).
        Complete(r)
}

func (r *MyReconciler) Reconcile(request ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    a := &A{}
    reconciler.Get(ctx, request.NamespacedName, a)
    b := &B{}
    reconciler.Get(ctx, NamespacedName{Name: a.Spec.bName, Namespace: a.Namespace}, b)
    if !a.DeletionTimestamp.IsZero() {
        clearOwnerReference(b)
        reconciler.Update(ctx, b)
        return ...
    }
    setOwnerReference(b.OwnerReference, a)
    reconciler.Update(ctx, b)
    // Other reconciliation logic
}
```

But Kubernetes API server acts more quickly: it detects B is orphan and deletes B, i.e., GC.

I also tried to add finalizer on B. But when my controller removes both `ownerReference` and `finalizers` from B, it's gone, since it's already been marked as deleted.

Any other config on B can be utilized to prevent such cascading deletion? Or any best practice to handle such dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do. You want your controller to be triggered by updates to A and B but not cascade delete B when A is deleted?

Comment: Providing code snippets would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a finalizer to A, so that when A is deleted, in the finalizer logic you remove the OwnerReference from B. This way A's deletion is not orphaning B in Kubernetes GC's eyes, as when A is deleted after the finalizer logic, it does not own anything.

Comment: How exactly is that done (configured)?

Comment: Here's an example of implementing a Finalizer logic from the operator-sdk: https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/advanced-topics/#external-resources

Comment: Much like in OP's code, but with a finalizer on a, that is cleared only after the ownerReference has been removed from b.